# Katalon - Using different Test data file for a test case depending on environment

Tags: automated-tests, data-driven-tests, katalon-studio

I'd like to have the option to run my tests with different test data depending on the environment I'm in, as they are slightly different.

My current setup: Test suite -> Test Cases each with 1 test data (excel file). I run checks (based off execution profile) to determine the environment and adjust the domain URL accordingly.

If I add a second data file to a test case, is there a way I can add logic to pick a specific test data file during execution time?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use "excel_file_1" for "default" execution profile, and "excel_file_2" for other execution profiles, use this:

```
import com.kms.katalon.core.configuration.RunConfiguration as RC
import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory as TestDataFactory

if (RC.getExecutionProfile()=='default'){
    def data = TestDataFactory.findTestData("excel_file_1")
    } else {
    def data = TestDataFactory.findTestData("excel_file_2")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just for clarity, I will explain most of the process to accomplish this.

- You could create different profiles for this (Generally used for environment variables).
  [Katalon Profiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s58hz.png)
- You may then enter keywords (which are GlobalVariables) to get or set
  your data (URLs, locations, etc.)
- Remember to add your test case(s) in a test suite
- You may then create separate build commands to test each profile you
  created by clicking Build CMD & specifying the execution profile

  [Specify profile in Build CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpuGi.png)

This way you can use something like TeamCity to run each cases or a combination thereof

Comment: Given a CI to run the build, this is the preferred answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this works as Katalon have more that one Test Case in test suite

```
import com.kms.katalon.core.configuration.RunConfiguration as RC
import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory as TestDataFactory

if (RC.getExecutionProfile()=='default'){
    def data = TestDataFactory.findTestData("excel_file_1")
    } else {
    def data = TestDataFactory.findTestData("excel_file_2")
}
```

In above code below question comes

1. whats 'data' variable
2. what if we have few more test cases and that too have data sheet